# Google Maps API for IOS map showing as black screen with Google logo in the bottom left

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I previously had a Google Map showing within my app, but now it just shows as a black screen with the Google logo in the bottom left corner on the simulator like this: 
[image]
It does work when I run it on my device though. I have tried creating a new API key, restarting my simulator, erasing and resetting the simulator.

Comment: May I know the error logs that you are getting? Can you also check if your API key is restricted?

Answer (score 0):

Import google map in appdelegate class

```
import GoogleMaps
```

Add this code in didfinishlaunched

```
 GMSServices.provideAPIKey(YOUR_API_KEY)
```

Add UIView in view controller and assign this class to the UIVIEW from storyboard

```
   GMSMapView
```

Map will come fine right after that.

Comment: Yeah I have that in my code. Like I said, it works fine when I run it on my iPhone so i think it is a problem with the simulator.